# iOs create new table cell from a few strings

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsstring, nsarray

I am receiving some strings in my SecondViewController.
In this viewcontroller i have a tableView but not yet any tableCells.

I am receiving this information:

```
2013-01-14 11:24:22.342 Scanner[16200:c07] (
    123456,
    "Jeans lynn skinny coj glass",
    "119.90",
    "S, M, L, XL",
    "G-Star"
)
2013-01-14 11:24:22.342 Scanner[16200:c07] jsonstring:{"2":"G-Star","3":null,"product":"Jeans lynn skinny coj glass","4":"119.90","maten":"S, M, L, XL","5":"S, M, L, XL","barcode":"123456","afbeelding":null,"0":"123456","winkel":"G-Star","prijs":"119.90","1":"Jeans lynn skinny coj glass"}
2013-01-14 11:24:22.342 Scanner[16200:c07] barcode:123456
2013-01-14 11:24:22.343 Scanner[16200:c07] product:Jeans lynn skinny coj glass
2013-01-14 11:24:22.343 Scanner[16200:c07] prijs:119.90
2013-01-14 11:24:22.343 Scanner[16200:c07] maten:S, M, L, XL
2013-01-14 11:24:22.343 Scanner[16200:c07] winkel:G-Star
```

From this code

```
    array = [[NSArray alloc] init];
    array = a;
    NSLog(@"%@", a);
    string = [[NSString alloc] init];
    string = s;
    NSLog(@"jsonstring:%@", s);
    NSString * barcode = [a objectAtIndex:0];
    NSLog(@"barcode:%@", barcode);
    NSString * product = [a objectAtIndex:1];
    NSLog(@"product:%@", product);
    NSString * prijs = [a objectAtIndex:2];
    NSLog(@"prijs:%@", prijs);
    NSString * maten = [a objectAtIndex:3];
    NSLog(@"maten:%@", maten);
    NSString * winkel = [a objectAtIndex:4];
    NSLog(@"winkel:%@", winkel);
```

Does anyone know how to put this in a new cell with a the label from that cell "123456", with an image next to it, and the other information in a subviewcontroller?

I am willing to put a bounty on this question after 2 days

Comment: I will put the answer after 2 days. :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use UITableViewDelegate http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html.

using:

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView (return the number of sections you want in your tableview)
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section (returning the number of cells you want for a specific section)

and of course:

tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:

example:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

return 1;

}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

return [array count];

}
```

and your cell:

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    // Set up the cell...

  cell.text = @"lol";


    return cell;
    }
```

Comment: Should i create in my viewcontroller.xib the tableView and cell? or only the tableview

Comment: Creating the TableView will automatically create cell when implementing

     - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath; method.

Comment: I have a question. i inserted your method. But how can i call the function that there should be made a new cell? How do i call the function to create a new cell

Comment: Actually the `cellFowRowAtIndexPath`: is automatically called when the `numberOfRowsInSection:`method is not returning 0. 

So if you want to add cell to your UITableView just implement the `UITableViewDelegate` in your viewcontroller, set the delegate and datasource to your uitableview with :

`tableview.delegate = self;
tableview.dataSource=self; `

and do something like:

`cell.textLabel.text = [array objectAtIndex:index];` in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`method.

Comment: Still not working. What i have now is:

Comment: Wait let me move this discussion to chat

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22821/tableview-cells